# Need to save contact info through website subscription form to different database in different region

Tags: web8, audience-manager

I have a requirement in which all website(except one) should save user contacts details on the default audience subscription database which is the working behavior, but one website which get published from same CMS server and also hosted on same CD server on which all websites are hosted, should save contact details on different audience subscription database which is on another cloud server.

So here my question is that how and where configuration needs to change for that single website so that contact details get save on the different database not on the default/existing database.
And also need to configure separate SYNC services to sync new subscription database with CM's AM DB.